# JavaScript isCurrency() failing

Tags: javascript

hey guys should be a easy one...I have some javascript that is turning my input values into currency values.  Problem is it will fail if I try to type in .5   heres is my code:

```
function handleCurrency(formName,fieldName)
{
    var enteredValue = document.forms[formName].elements[fieldName].value;

    if ( enteredValue.isCurrency() )
    {
        alert("This is currency " + enteredValue )
        // Put the nicely formatted back into the text box.
        document.forms[formName].elements[fieldName].value = enteredValue.toCurrency();
    }
}
```

jsp:

```
 <td><input type="text" name="replacementCost" onchange="handleCurrency('NsnAdd','replacementCost')" value="<ctl:currencyFormat currency='${form.replacementCost}'/>" onkeypress="javascript:return noenter();" <c:if test="${!lock.locked}">disabled="disabled"</c:if> /></td>
```

How can I make it so that .5 is allowable also to be formatted?

custom javascript:

```
var patternWithCommas = new RegExp("^\\s*\\$?-?(\\d{1,3}){1}(,\\d{3}){0,}(\\.\\d{1,2})?\\s*$");
var patternWithoutCommas = new RegExp("^\\s*\\$?-?\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?\\s*$");

function stringIsCurrency()
{
if (patternWithoutCommas.test(this))
{
    return true;
}
else if (patternWithCommas.test(this))
{
    return true;
}
return false;
}

function stringToCurrency()
{
if (this == '') return this;

var str = this.replace(/[$,]+/g,'');

sign = (str == (str = Math.abs(str)));
str = Math.floor(str*100+0.50000000001);
cents = str%100;
str = Math.floor(str/100).toString();

if (cents<10) cents = "0" + cents;

for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((str.length-(1+i))/3); i++)
{
    str = str.substring(0,str.length-(4*i+3))+','+
          str.substring(str.length-(4*i+3));
}

str = '$' + ((sign)?'':'-') + str + '.' + cents;

return str;
}

String.prototype.isCurrency = stringIsCurrency;
String.prototype.toCurrency = stringToCurrency;
```

basically it needs to allow .5 and not just 0.5

this needs to be updated:

```
var patternWithCommas = new RegExp("^\\s*\\$?-?(\\d{1,3}){1}(,\\d{3}){0,}(\\.\\d{1,2})?\\s*$");
```

Comment: my bad...we have it custom built

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shown your code for `isCurrency`.

Here's how I would do it:

```
function isCurrency( val )
{
    return /^\$?(?:\d[\d,]*)?(?:.\d\d?)?$/.test( val );
}
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?3103a

---

Now that you have provided your code, here's my proposed solution.

While there are many things I would have done differently,
in order to keep the spirit of your code, just change this:

```
var patternWithCommas = new RegExp("^\\s*\\$?-?(\\d{1,3}){1}(,\\d{3}){0,}(\\.\\d{1,2})?\\s*$");
var patternWithoutCommas = new RegExp("^\\s*\\$?-?\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?\\s*$");
```

to this:

```
var patternWithCommas = /^\s*\$?-?((\d{1,3}){1}(,\d{3})?)?(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/;
var patternWithoutCommas = /^\s*\$?-?(\d+)?(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/;
```

which would make the dollar amount optional.

Comment: @DocHoliday - I posted some more code for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey that really helped....thanks alot....I seemed to get easily confused by regex